# Leer Json con ajax con nombres sin comillas

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Busco leer a través de `jquery` y `ajax` un objeto `json` desde un servidor externo. Al hacer la solicitud el servidor me retorna un supuesto archivo json con el siguiente formato:

```
{
 Status: 'Success',
 Data:{
 'primero': {
    phone:'5281128043'
   }
 }
}
```

Donde los nombres de los valores se encuentran sin comillas.

La solicitud la realizo mediante la siguiente etiqueta `HTML`:

```
<script type="text/Javascript" src="http://www.servlets.org/Ads.aspx?
&callback=myCallback"></script>
```

Ya que la información proviene de un servidor externo, no tengo control sobre su sintaxis y al solicitarlo me retorna el siguiente error:

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement.

¿Cómo podría recibir este archivo`json` escrito en ese formato sin comillas ?
¿Tal vez con algún atributo `type` diferente dentro de la etiqueta script?

Comment: Agrega más info; como tiene la petición Ajax, que recibes (si en realidad es un json, no sea un texto o html...) y el punto en el cual se genera el error que mencionas. El error por si solo no permite orientarte más claramente.

Comment: Por favor agrega más información, ese error NO es del Json en sí, si no del tratamiento.

Comment: Exacto, como puedes observar con ese formato me retorna el servidor el archivo, que tratamiento deberia aplicarle para poderlo utilizar ?

Comment: El tratamiento que le des en tu Callback.

Answer (score 3):

El formato es <del>in</del>... Nononono, es totalmente **correcto**.

JSON es en realidad un trozo de Javascript que se incorpora al código; este trozo de código representa una estructura de datos (un elemento simple, un array de elementos, una tabla asociativa de elementos)

En

```
{"nombre" : "pedro"}
```

tienes un array asociativo con un solo elemento, con clave `nombre` y valor `pedro`.

JS permite que quites las comillas del elemento de la izquierda y lo sigue considerando como una etiqueta; aunque no así con el de la derecha<sup>1</sup>. Así:

```
{nombre : "pedro"}
```

Es exactamente lo mismo que el ejemplo anterior.

El problema es que JSON **son sólo los datos**. Lo que te llega de JSON lo debes asignar a una variable Javascript y procesar después con tu Javascript. Lo que estás haciendo es cargar un trozo **incompleto** de programa en el  interprete Javascript, que muy lógicamente se queja.

Lo que tienes que hacer es, **desde el código JavaScript**, hacer una llamada Ajax a la URL y asignar el valor retornado a una variable Javascript. Y a partir de ahí, a sacar los datos de la estructura.

Para que veas la diferencia, una sentencia JS completa (que no hace nada, sólo define la estructura) sería:

```
var misDatos = {
    Status: 'Success',
    Data:{
      'primero': {
         phone:'5281128043'
         }
      }
    };
```

La gracia del Ajax es que el programa JS y los datos van por separados, por lo que puedes volver a cargar los datos sin cargar toda la página, obtener los datos de otros servidores, etc. El problema es que la forma de obtenerlos es algo más complicada que simplemente escribiendo el código JS.

Aquí tienes un buen ejemplo para empezar (en inglés sorry, pero si buscas por "JSON Ajax" seguro que encontrarás más). https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_ajax_example.htm

---

<sup>1</sup>Si quitas las comillas del elemento de la derecha lo interpreta como el nombre de una variable.

Comment: El servidor al que hago la peticion me retorna un formato "JSON" escrito de la siguiente manera {
Status: 'Success',

Data:{
 'primero': {
  phone:'5281128043'
 }
 }
} 
Ya que es respuesta del servidor no puedo modificar su sintaxis,  por lo tanto me gustaria saber la manera de recibir este archivo adecuadamente porque por el momento el navegador me retorna error:
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa es la notación de objeto literal de JavaScript, donde se permite escribir las claves sin comillas, y otra JSON, donde el estándar dice que hay que utilizar comillas dobles. No tiene por qué ser así, pero es así.

Si no puedes cambiar nada en el servidor, necesitarás cambiar la cadena devuelta antes de parsearla.

Utiliza esta expresión regular (la he convertido de PHP, no sé 100% si funcionará en JavaScript, aunque debería):

`json = json.replace(/([{,])(\s*)([A-Za-z0-9_\-]+?)\s*:/g, '$1"$3":');`

Y después ya haces:

`var data = JSON.parse(json);`